# Short function to remove unnecessary whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, regex

I have a function consisting of one line of code:

```
def trimString(string):
    """ Remove unnecessary whitespace. """
    return re.sub('\s+', ' ', string).strip()
```

But I've been debating with myself whether the following would be better, seeing as explicit > implicit.

```
def trimString(string):
    """ Remove unnecessary whitespace. """
    string = re.sub('\s+', ' ', string).strip()
    return string
```

So which is preferable, the former or the latter? And why is that the case?

The question may be off-topic but I find myself asking it often enough and thought this was the place to ask.

Comment: I think anyone reading this who understands what `re.sub` and `.strip()` do will understand that this will return a string. The doctring and type hints as suggested by @eric.m make it even clearer without adding an extra variable.

Comment: @HoboProber I'll keep this in mind going forward as I don't want to bloat the code while still keeping things explicit. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the shorter, the better. Since you are in Python 3, if you really want to make explicit that the function is returning a string, you can use [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```py
def trimString(string) -> str:
```

You can also specify it in the parameter:

```py
def trimString(string: str) -> str:
```

(keep in mind that Python will ignore type hints, but some IDEs like PyCharm use it to detect warnings and errors)

On a side note, you should try to follow the [PEP 8 styling conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); the function name should be in camel case, so `trim_string`.

Comment: I hadn't thought of type hints before but it seems like something I'll be very into. I've seen people deliberately avoiding the naming conventions suggested by PEP 8, namely on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names/160830#160830) and figured I'd do the same simply because of habit and preference. But I still have my doubts. Anyways, good answer :)

Comment: I used to avoid the naming conventions before, because I was used to programming Java. Now when I look at my old Python code it looks ugly since it's not what my brain expects to see in Python. I guess it's a matter of habit.